# Verifying assets with the App Store in Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, coronasdk

I am trying to submit my app to the app store using Application Loader , but the submitting process stuck at Verifying assets with the App Store. I have been trying to submit my app for two days and and it still stuck there. I know that maybe a common issue , but I tried the solutions  written in the other question but nothing worked with me :/ my app is built using corona sdk , does anyone have an idea ? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and in my case it seems to be related to the LAN network restrictions of my company. The only solution I've found is to use my phone connection (via tethering) and it worked.

Comment: Tethering fixed me as well.