# xcode stucks on verifying assets with the iTunes store while uploading the archive

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to upload my archived app to the AppStore but the xCode stuck on upload phase and shows below message:

```
verifying assets with the iTunes store...
```

I read below links:

[Application loader stuck at the stage of “Verifying assets with the iTunes Store”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494065/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-verifying-assets-with-the-itunes-store)

[Verifying assets with the App Store in Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977536/verifying-assets-with-the-app-store-in-application-loader)

and restart the xCode and my Mac; also updated the Mac but still the problem exist.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Try via `Application Loader`!

Comment: same on Application Loader

Comment: my account need to be renewed since 20 Oct, May it need to renew before publishing new app?

Comment: obviously, if your one year is completed for your apple developer account then you can't put app on appstore until you renew it!!

Comment: it is not compeleted yet, it is going to compelete on 20 Oct

Comment: Then that shouldn't be an issue!

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42815259/1008984

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I change my internet connection and used a connection from another Internet Provider. By using the new connection the verification phase passed and my binary uploaded successfully.

Comment: Same here. I was using eduroam network to upload my build. switching to another one solved the issue

Comment: This solved my issue, after so many times of certificate deletion and recreation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the **expired credit card**, once I put in the updated data it went on and completed the uploading process.

Make sure there is nothing incomplete in your developer profile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seemed to be because I had not accepted the updated terms in App Store Connect. I agreed to them and it worked instantly.